# Save files relative to the dynamically determined base dir

Tags: gulp

`gulpjs/gulp/issues/`

I have the following structure:

```
|-->view/
    `-->foo/
        `-->bar/
            `-->less/
               |-->a.less
               |-->b.less
               `-->inner/
                   `-->c.less
```

My `process.cwd()` is the `view` folder. The output that I want is:

```
|-->view/
    `-->foo/
        `-->bar/
            |-->less/
            |  |-->a.less
            |  |-->b.less
            |  `-->inner/
            |      `-->c.less
            `-->css/
               |-->a.css
               |-->b.css
               `-->inner/
                   `-->c.css
```

My `gulp.src()` looks something like this:

```js
gulp.task('lessc', function(cb) {
    gulp.src('**/less/**/*.less').
        .pipe(less())
        // ... how to save files relative to the dynamically determined base dir 'bar'?
});
```